# What would cause Revit Linked files to not load aligned for some projects?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In forge viewer, I display Revit files with their linked files.
To do this, I do the following:
-Load model from main file (main_urn), at offset 0.
-Load model from linked file (link_urn), also at offset 0.

For most of revit projects I import, it works perfectly, linked models are displayed on top of main model.
But, on some revit projects, I have models, that do not superpose at all, event if all are loaded at offset 0.
While I am in revit software, my linked files are clearly aligned with main file.

Is this behaviour known? What would solve this (except manual calibration/positioning)?

Note: I can reproduce the same not only in my app code, but with the code provided here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/aggregate-multi-models-sequence-forge-viewer
Note2: The files having this issue cannot be made public.

Thank you,

Comment: I understand that you cannot share the actual files, but could you perhaps share more details on how the links between the files are configured? E.g. according to the [docs](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Revit-Model/files/GUID-D184A004-D0BF-44D1-9C02-99480B129CAD-htm.html), the linked models can be positioned as `Auto - Center to Center`, `Auto - Origin to Origin`, `Auto - By Shared Coordinates`, etc. I'm wondering if the misalignment is caused by one of these.

Comment: Is there a way to get this info if link is already imported? I can do it by reimporting the link but cannot check what is the current one. I keep searching meanwhile. Thanks

Comment: If I take my revit files, and import them as links, they are already misaligned. Are there any recommendations to deliver to Revit designer when working on files/links so it will be fine on forge viewer? (or should we consider, if it displays well in revit, it will in forge?). Same question on forge viewer side, is it safe to move origin to {0,0,0} for each model, or could it break links?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @Fabien. When you right-click _Revit Links_ in _Project Browser_ and choose _New Link..._, a new dialog should open with a _Positioning_ dropdown at the very bottom, with options like `Auto - Center to Center`, `Auto - Origin to Origin`, etc. What do you see there? I'm thinking that experimenting with those options might help with the positioning in the Forge Viewer.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the UI I was referring to: https://imgur.com/a/61WGzKK.

Comment: On Revit files/links I have with the issue, link import is done with mode [Auto - Project Base Point to Project Base Point]. Any recommandations with this? (When I import with Origin to Origin, I see the same offset between model I have on forge, but main idea is to avoid customer to change how his files are designed)

Comment: Note: when I import all my links with main file in zip file, all is aligned. But I have no way to load/unload links, all elements are merged.

Comment: When a Revit model (with additional linked models) is translated into the Forge Viewer format, it becomes one scene, and you cannot "unload" parts of it later. Regarding the different _Positioning_ options, you'll probably need to experiment with those. If you have existing Revit models from your customers that are not positioned properly, I'm afraid in those cases it'll be hard to re-position them without any additional info.